# How to Query fields within a Gridfs object in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I am having trouble with gridfs in python. I have my json file uploaded but now want to query data in the file. How does one do this. Here is an example of the code that I have

```
from pymongo import MongoClient 
import gridfs

client = <connection_string>

db = client.testdb
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)

result = db.fs.files.find({})
print(list(result))
print(result)
```

This code returns a cursor object and casting that object to a list just gives me the file object fields like _id, md5, chunkSize, etc....

Here is an example JSON file

```
{'name': 'andrew',
 'age': 90
 'fav_foods': ['pizza', 'cheeseburger']
}
```

Using gridfs how would I query the fav_foods field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. GridFS handles (stores & retrieves) binary data, there is no provision in MongoDB for querying the contents of files stored in GridFS. If you wish to use MQL you need to insert data as documents.

Comment: ok so if you have a JSON larger than 16mb you have to break it up into smaller documents then insert it. Is GridFS just used to pull entire files/images/audio down?